# Mocking C++ classes with dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, googlemock

Say you're testing class `A` and it has a [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) of `B` which has a dependency injection of `C`.
So you mock `B` but the only constructor it has requires an injection of `C`, so do you have to mock `C` as well and inject the mocked `C` into the mocked `B` and only then inject it to `A`?
What if you have 5 consecutive dependancies?

What are the alternatives?

I use [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/), so a specific answer would help as well.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In this case you should inject by pointer and not by reference, then you could pass a NULL pointer. This would work assuming you're object is indeed a mock and not a fake object, therefore it has no real dependency on the injected object.

For `boost::shared_ptr` you could do the following:

```
boost::shared_ptr<C> null_c_ptr;
MockB mock_b(null_c_ptr);
```

Answer (score 7):

Emile has the right idea, you should depend on interfaces not concrete classes.  So in your example it would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    int x;
};

class B {
public:
    ~B(){};
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class ConcreteB : public B{
public:
    ConcreteB(C c) : m_c(c) {}
    void doSomething(){
        std::cout << "HelloWorld" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    C m_c;
};
class A{
public:
    A(B *b): m_b(b){}

    void functionToTestWithSideEffect(){
        m_b->doSomething();
    }
private:
    B *m_b;

};

//#include <gmock/gmock.h>

int main() {
    C c;
    c.x = 42;
    ConcreteB b(c);
    A a(&b);
    a.functionToTestWithSideEffect();
    return 0;
}
```

In your tests you create a mock B which does not rely on any class C.  Then you are only testing the interface with B.  In this way you break A's dependency on C. Creating a mock B that doesn't depend on C is pretty simple:

```
class MockB : public B {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(doSomething, void());
};
```

Comment: Good yet cumbersome solution. I would prefer having the framework have a macro to automate this, if at all possible... (opened a thread about it here http://groups.google.com/group/googlemock/browse_thread/thread/2ed342a384456795)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I think what you want might be impossible to do with macros since it would require macros to parse the c++ source since there is no reflection available.

Comment: You may want to read this from the googlemock cookbook on interfaces: http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Alternative_to_Mocking_Concrete_Classes.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the design so that the classes depend on interfaces instead of concrete classes, you get rid of the constructor problems. Besides improving testability, it may also improve reusability and maintainability, at the cost of more code (interfaces).

Comment: Could you elaborate? Would this remove the necessity of dependency injection?

Comment: It does not remove the dependency injection, only that you inject an interface. So compile time only the interface has to be in scope. This reduces the coupling and (in your example) C does not come into sight anymore since you do not a concrete B anymore.