# C++ dependency injection - by reference or by boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, pass-by-reference, shared-ptr

In cases where constructor dependency injection is required, what are the considerations for using injection **by reference** vs. using **boost::shared_ptr**?

Is there another common way of doing it? How does it compare to the two methods above?

Comment: +1: I love dependency injection!

Comment: Using a pointer may help in certain scenarios. See following answer for such a case while testing the class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726580/mocking-c-classes-with-dependency-injection/5836747#5836747

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your choice on how you want to manage the lifetime of the object you're injecting. The overall architecture will probably dictate which choice makes the most sense. With a reference, something at a higher level must manage the object lifetime; with `shared_ptr` the lifetime will be managed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Previously I have used both methods.

The advantage of using the shared pointer approach means that you can pass ownership of the injected dependencies to the consumer.

If you use the reference based approach then destruction of the injected dependencies is much more deterministic. I.e. it occurs once all processing in the consumers has completed.

Answer (score 2):

I remember seeing some code that did it with `unique_ptr` (or maybe `auto_ptr`). This seems to be better than "by reference": there is no need to manage the ownership of the injected object. This might be faster than using `shared_ptr`: no reference counting is involved. This might be more confusing though: it involves transfer of ownership, and `auto_ptr` has some pitfalls.

Comment: `unique_ptr` and `auto_ptr` don't give you the possibility of sharing the object. Again, whether this will be a problem depends on the overall architecture.

Comment: Its a good choice if the object owns (does not share) the injected object.

Answer (score -1):

The question you need to ask yourself is: who owns the object? In a typical DI scenario, it is the consumer object. In that case, I would pass a raw pointer to the constructor and store it into something like `unique_ptr`. If the ownership is shared or not clear, than of course, use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Huh?  It should *never* be the consumer in DI - what if other objects need to use that instance as well?

Comment: @BlueRaja: Strictly speaking, it can be either way - DI is orthogonal to the aggregation vs. composition dilemma.

Comment: I would never pass a RAW pointer anywere. If nothing else wrapping a pointer in a smart pointer provides documentation (in the source) of what is supposed to happen to the object passing RAW p;pointers is just horrible and confusing.

Comment: @Martin: What kind of smart pointer would you pass to a constructor of a container that is taking ownership of the dynamically allocated object?

Comment: I vote for thinking about ownership and scopes together when making decisions like this.

Comment: @ Nemanja Trifunovic: boost::ptr_vector and other ptr containers that are designed to take ownership of pointers all accept std::auto_ptr to indicate the transfer of ownership to the container. If your container is not specifically designed to take ownership then of the pointer you should not be using it to hold pointers as it will not be exception safe.

Comment: @Martin: The topic is about DI containers, not "collections". Passing a pointer to a constructor and assigning it via initializer list is guaranteed to be exception-safe. Sure, you can use std::auto_ptr instead, but there is no benefit of using that. Besides, auto_ptr is deprecated in C++11

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic: You brought up containers not me (I was merly answering your comment). Sure auto_ptr is depreciated in the next standard, but you can use std::unique_ptr (the auto_ptr replacement) instead it does the same thing.

Comment: @Martin: Yep, I meant consumer, not container (see my original answer). Anyway, I still don't see an advantage of using unique_ptr as an argument to a constructor of a DI consumer object. As I said, passing and assigning raw pointers are guaranteed to be exception-safe (no-exception guarantee, in fact).

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic: As I noted in my first comment it documents intent. Without it a maintainer does not know if you did it accidentally or on purpose. RAW pointers have now ownership semantics so it cant document intent. Smart pointers are not only safe but they document the intent of the developer.