# How do I use GMock with dependency injection?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a class which carries a couple of dependencies which I'd like to mock using Google Mocks, in order to test the class with Google Test.

Simplified, I have the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
template<typename TDep>
class SUT {
private:
    TDep dependency;

public:
    explicit SUT(const TDep& dep) : dependency(dep) { }
    SUT(const SUT& other) : dependency(dep.other) { }

    // some methods that use the dependency
}
```

I also have an interface for the dependency,

```
class IDependency {
public:
    virtual double calculateCoolStuff(double) const = 0;
    virtual ~IDependency() { };
}
```

and a mock object

```
class MockDependency {
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(calculateCoolStuff, double(double));
};
```

However, when I try to compile something like

```
MockDependency mock;
SUT sut(mock);
```

I get errors stating `error: use of deleted function MockDependency(const MockDependency&)`, i.e. there is no copy-constructor of the mocked object. I found [this discussion on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/GD73UXjQowE) which basically ends in making mock objects non-copyable, but allowing the user to add a copy constructor and define copy behavior manually. Very well:

```
class MockDependency {
public:
    MockDependency(const MockDependency& other) { }
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(calculateCoolStuff, double(double));
};
```

Now my code compiles, but if I run something like

```
MockDependency mock;
SUT sut(mock);

EXPECT_CALL(mock, calculateCoolStuff(2.0)).WillRepeatedly(Return(3.0));

sut.doStuff(); // Calls calculateCoolStuff
```

in a test, I get an error stating that the call was never set up. In other words, the instance `mock` which I can use to setup expectations, is no longer the same as the instance on `SUT` used for calculations. This makes testing with GMock and DI difficult, to say the least...

What is the best solution to this?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) Yes, I'm using poor man's DI. Not the topic of this conversation...</sup>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mocking C++ classes with dependency injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726580/mocking-c-classes-with-dependency-injection)

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: I read that question, but it doesn't solve my problem, since I inject by reference and not by pointer. The expectations aren't copied when the copy constructor of the mock object is invoked, and I'd rather not change this as it'd break the interface.

Comment: @TomasLycken Why not make the private member in `SUT` a reference?  That is, `TDep& dependency;`

Comment: @RA.That did solve my problem entirely. If you put it in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dependency injection with references by ensuring that your class member is a reference:

```
template<typename TDep>
class SUT {
private:
    TDep& dependency;  // Reference

    // etc.
}
```

Note that you no longer need a copy constructor on `MockDependency`.  As a rule, you need access to all instances of mock objects being used by your SUT to set up expectations on them.